# Will a body necessarily posses zero kinetic energy at infinity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, energy-conservation, potential-energy, projectile

I have been studying about gravitation for a while and most of the books(including fundamental of physics) while defining escape velocity assumes that **kinetic energy of a body at infinity is zero** (potential energy is zero too, but that's not my matter).

Now the question is why we take K.E.= zero at infinity. As for the gravitational field of earth escape speed is defined 11.2 Km/sec, what will happen if i throw a body with a speed of 90 Km/sec, will it still posses zero kinetic energy at infinity.

Hope you all got my question,if any query leave comment.

Hoping for a simplified answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Escape velocity is the *minimum* velocity needed to escape.   The minimum velocity results in zero kinetic energy at infinity.   But velocities *greater* than the escape velocity are possible, of course, and these result in a velocity at infinity that is greater than zero.

Comment: but the book says (as a generalised result) that when a body reaches infinity it stops and hence its kinetic energy is zero.

Comment: Your book is wrong, if it states it in the form you quoted.

Comment: Think of a body subjected to an everywhere zero potential with a finite initial speed. As the total energy coincides with the kinetical one and is conserved, when it reaches the infinity its velocity is the same as at the initial instant...

Comment: @sammygerbil I think what the OP says about what his book says is correct.   When a projectile is launched *at escape velocity*, its velocity is zero at infinity.  This is true.  But if it is launched at a speed *greater* than the escape velocity,  its velocity at infinity will not be zero.   If it's launched slower than escape velocity, it turns around and comes back.

Comment: Thanks, garyp. I didn't read the question properly. I will delete my comment.

Comment: @THELONEWOLF, to be sure, a body *never* reaches infinity; the velocity "at infinity" is the limiting velocity the body approaches as $r \rightarrow \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

> Will a body necessarily posses zero kinetic energy at infinity?

In this type of problem, it is assumed that:

- The *total* energy, $\mathrm{E = KE + PE}$, of the particle is conserved
- The gravitational potential is negative and approaches zero as $r \rightarrow \infty$.

Since $\mathrm{KE}$ cannot be negative, it follows that if the *total* energy $\mathrm{E}$ is non-negative, the particle can reach arbitrarily large $r$ and the particle's $\mathrm{KE}$ approaches $\mathrm{E}$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$.

Thus, if $\mathrm{E}$ is *exactly* zero, the particle's speed asymptotically approaches zero as $r \rightarrow \infty$ while if $\mathrm{E}$ is positive, the particle's speed approaches a non-zero positive constant as $r \rightarrow \infty$.

Lastly, in the case that $\mathrm{E \lt 0}$, the particle is *bound* and the greatest distance $r$ the particle can reach is when the particle's $\mathrm{KE}$ is zero:  $r_{max} = -\frac{GMm}{E}$

Answer (score 0):

Before we ask why we take Kinetic energy to be zero at infinity we could ask why we care about infinity in the first place ? To understand this we must first understand the problem. The problem is as follows: I am in the gravitational field of a massive body and I want to go to region where I will not feel its gravitational force. This is really important to understand because if I do not want to feel its gravitational force then my potential energy between me and the massive body has to be zero otherwise if there is some gravitational energy I can take a derivative of the formula $ \frac{GMm}{r}$ and get an non-zero force.

Looking at the equation for gravitational potential energy we see our solution, I have to go to $r =\infty $ in order to insure there is no force between me and the massive body.The main concern is to get to a region where the potential energy between me and the massive body is zero. Now I want to do the least amount of effort possible so when I reach $r=\infty $ I want to reach there with the least amount of velocity possible i.e $v=0$. So this mean escape velocity is the minimum velocity you need to escape a gravitational field of influence. No one said you could not go faster, you can but the escape velocity gives you the bench mark you need to achieve.